# Eclipse key binding for non-commands

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

There are many useful menu items of third-party plugins that are not Eclipse commands. I.e. Team->Update to Head from Subversion plugin, Rerun the last test from TesNG plugin and many others.

Is there a way to add key bindings for them and/or add them on the tool bar without modifying plugin.xml and source code of third-party plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Most keys can be configured in `Preferences -> General -> Keys`.

Comment: I mean those actions which are not in the list.